# Alert on custom identification

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I use TFS 2013 Update 2 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

How can I create an identification to a workitem where I can create an alert on?
I have workitems for a specific customer. I added a tag to those workitems. I want an alert when something changes with a workitem with that tag. Because alerts don't support tags, I created a custom field but I also can't set an alert with the "=" operator on that field.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of is to add a "tag" to the title of the workitem. We have the taggging and set the tag `Foo`. We also place the tag in the title like this `(Foo)`. Than we have a query that searches for workitems that only have the real tag and not the title tag. Of course also the other way around.

We are going to use this until the next version were hopefully this feature is added. See for the uservoices the following:
[Custom fields in work item alerts](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2436843-custom-fields-in-work-item-alerts) and [Use tags in alerts](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6059328-use-tags-in-alerts).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using tags can you try setting an area path for your specific customer, and put the work items under this area? Then you can use the custom alert template "A work item under a specified area path changes" to receive your alerts.

Comment: Thank you for your possible solution but this won't work. We have the new TFS 2013 Teams feature enabled. So every team has it's own area path. We have our own items but also the items of the specific customer (custom parts of the product).